# generating inline escaped html using Jade sintax

Tags: pug

Is there any way to generate escaped code using jade syntax?

This basically what i would like to do:

```
pre: code
  div
```

And the desired output would be:

```
<pre><code>  
  &lt;div&gt; &lt;/div&gt;
</code></pre>
```

But it does not work like this. it just outputs:

```
<pre><code>
  <div></div>
</code></pre>
```

It would be helpful for documentation for my project. Code would be shown on one half, and on the other it would be shown in action.

Comment: Check this out http://jade-lang.com/reference/interpolation/

Comment: You also could look into improvements on how jade handles filters, such as [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jade-filter).

Answer (score 1):

```
p
  = 'This code is <escaped>!'
```

produces

```
<p>This code is &lt;escaped&gt;!
</p>
```